# keeping uisearchbar always visible in uitableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

I have searched this question on google already but I could not find a good answer, so kindly respond with a good answer.

I am using a uisearchbar in uitableview to search data in the uitableview.

When ever I scroll down the uisearchbar remains on the top of the uitableview so if I have to search again I have to scroll to top.

I want uisearchbar to remain visible all the time. How do I do that?

I am working in swift 2 btw.

Thanks.

Comment: Add separate `UISearchBar` and `UITableView`.

Comment: How can I do that? Can you explain in simple steps

Comment: 1) Add UISearchBar on top of your view. 2) After search bar, add tableview. For eg:- the height of search bar is 40px, then tableview must start from 40px(y-Axis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Navigationbar to your class and Add the searchbar to the navigation item titleView.

```
  self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar
```

Another option is to use `UITableView`. Just place the tableView  below the searchbar.

Comment: No it is not working. I have already added a button to the navigation item title view

Comment: then you can keep it on top of tableview . you cannot use uitableViewcontroller, you have to use uitableview and place the tableview below the searchbar.

Comment: Hi Teja, how do you place the tableview below the searchbar in code? Thanks